# Horizontal organization using CSS/HTML5

Tags: css, html, grouping

[image: the goal]

Above is what I am trying to create as a login form (although there should be a mirror of 'login' after the right brace that says 'signup'). I'm having trouble getting the objects to line up horizontally as I wish. The second image (below) shows what I have. Yikes.

[image: hmmm, we've got work to do]

I obviously don't want the fieldset around it, but I our it there to try and group the username and password fields. Here is my code thus far. The HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
  <title>Login</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}jquery1-6.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}login.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<script>
  function login(){
      if($('username').text === '') alert('Please enter your username');
      else if($('password') === '') alert('Please enter your password');
      $('loginForm').submit();
  }
</script>

<body>
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL}}logo.png" class='center'>
<br/>
<span class='login_signup_button'>
    <a title='click to login' onClick='login()'>
    login
    </a>
</span>
<form method = 'POST' action='login' id='loginForm'>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="username">username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" face="helvetica"/>
    </br>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" face="AmericanTypewriter"/>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<span class='login_signup_button' value='submit'>
    <a title='signup for omnicloud' href='signup' class='login_signup_button'>
    signup
    </a>
</span>
</body>
```

and the CSS (which is imported into the HTML):

```
@font-face{
  font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
  src:url('AmericanTypewriter.TTF');
}

body{
    background-color:rgb(48,94,255);
}

image.center{
    /*display: block; */
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:500px;
}

/* Used for braces */
h1{ 
    font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
    font-size:234pt;    
    color:rgb(249,255,41);
}

/* Used for login, signup, username, password */
p{
    font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
    font-size:42pt
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}

fieldset{
  border: 10px solid rgb(255,255,255);
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
}

a{
    background-color:rgb(48,94,255);
    font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
    font-size:42pt
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
}

.login_signup_button button{
    background-color:rgb(48,94,255);
    font-family:AmericanTypewriter;
    font-size:42pt
    color:rgb(255,255,255)
    border-bottom:0;
  border-right:0;
  border-top:0;
  border-left:0;
  display:block;
}
.login_signup_button a:hover{
    background-color:rgb(249,255,41);
    color:rgb(48,94,255);
}
```

**EDIT**: updated code to fix the action of login, added js function, formatted labels for s

Comment: I've never heard of `<image>` and `<block>` tags. Perhaps they are the problem?

Comment: me neither, It's probably from another planet.

Comment: <span> does not have a "value" attribute. <input> does not have a "face" attribute. <form> needs a "method" attribute (get or post). Maybe you should brush up on your HTML a bit. http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @ddrace okay but I want login to be the submit button for the field, but not in the field. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: If you're OK using Javascript, you can just add an onClick attribute to your <a> tag that fires a javascript function that submits the form. (http://goo.gl/a17p8) Otherwise, you'd need to use an image button (<input type="image"...) and make the "login" text an image.

Comment: Oh thanks that would work great! About the organization, though, how can I get it to go (left->right) login { username/password } signup?

Comment: Really suggest _not_ using points for font sizing on screen media. Nothing but pain down that road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qwwkc/24/). (Just a rough start).

Note that I'm using an image for the brackets (not seen here). I don't know which version of American Typewriter you're using, but I doubt it will look that thin at that size, and it's probably not worth loading an entire weight of a typeface just for those two characters. Sometimes an image is just better, even though it might not seem as elegant.

Note that I'm a common image replacement technique for the logo. This is better for SEO that simply using an `<img>` with alt text. (Which you should always include if you choose that route instead.)

Edit: And if you do want to use the font for the brackets, you might try using [CSS :before and :after pseudo-classes](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/beforeafter.html) to add the content around the fieldset or whatever you use as your container for those form elements.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you want to maintain grouping of fields which fieldset provides but not happy with the lines around those fields. If that is the case then you can mark filedset border as none.

```
fieldset {
border: none;
}
```

Comment: yep they are just there for testing

Comment: @Chris Do you like curly braces around those fields { }. If yes  then you have to use two images { and }

Comment: I can't just have them as giant text? I do like them a lot

Comment: To use field horizontally i would suggest you to use table property. Ex: <table><tr><td>Put Label for username </td> <td> text for username </td> </tr> </table> will align label and text in one row. Table will be hidden and not be visible and that way you will get perfect alignment. Of course for braces you can use giant images :)

Comment: but if I move from a form to a table will I still be able to submit? Or will I have to write a bunch of code to correctly handle the equivalent?

Comment: @Chris Yes you will be able to submit also you can think table as UI or view. Just try sample table with multiple columns and rows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are trying to do is to have the input field show next to your text label.

This is how i would write the HTML:

```
<body>
<img src="logo.png" class="center"/>

<div id="signin">
    <form action="path-to-submit" method="post">
        <label for="username-field">Username</label>
        <input id="username-field" type="text" name="username"/><br/>

        <label for="password-field">Password</label>
        <input id="password-field" type="password" name="password"/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>

        <a href="path-to-signup.html">Signup for Omnicloud</a>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

Because  and  are inline elements, they will show up next to each-other.  Using the br tag will create a line-break for the next set of fields.

Comment: when you have 'path-to-signup.html', how can I make that a specific url such as example.com/signup? As of right now, it just appends signup to the end of the url and tries that...

Comment: Maybe i'm not understanding you correctly?  It's just a simple anchor tag, so you change it to wherever you want it to go. ie: <a href="http://www.google.com">Take me to google</a>